# DayOfWeek - get day number

Tags: vb.net, regional-settings

I have this method:

```
Dim dayofweek As Integer = CInt(DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek)
Dim startdayvalue As Integer = 0
Select Case args(1).ToLower
    Case "monday"
        startdayvalue = 1
    Case "tuesday"
        startdayvalue = 2
    Case "wednesday"
        startdayvalue = 3
    Case "thursday"
        startdayvalue = 4
    Case "friday"
        startdayvalue = 5
    Case "saturday"
        startdayvalue = 6
    Case "sunday"
        startdayvalue = 7
End Select

Return (dayofweek - startdayvalue + 7) Mod 7 + 1
```

args(1) is the a day like "monday" to "sunday" which the user can throw in. I want it to always start with value 1 for the given regional settings. I guess something is wrong with my last line because it gives me the wrong values. For example it gives me Monday = 1 (correct) Tuesday = 7 (incorrect) Sunday (2). In my regional settings week starts with Monday and should be one and Sunday 7.

Comment: This is VB, not C#.

Comment: Whats wring with `DateTime.Now.Day`?  (assuming day number means the date)

Comment: Sorry about c#. I am interested in a result of 1 - 7 - not the actual day of month.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't try to work against the abstraction the .NET Framework supplies.

You can obtain the generic DayOfWeek number from your given culture:

```
Dim ci As System.Globalization.CultureInfo
ci = New System.Globalization.CultureInfo("de-DE")
Dim fdow As System.DayOfWeek
fdow = ci.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek
```

You can use this `DayOfWeek` to compare against your DateTime.DayOfWeek to identify if this date is on the first day of the week for your culture.